# CSS not loaded with AsseticBundle

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

I want to declare my CSS using Assetic with this code :

```
# app/config/config.yml
    assetic:
        debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
        use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
```

and in the layout.html.twig:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/ocplatform/css/main.css'  %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"  type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

The HTML element is generated :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/css/519c4f6_main_1.css" type="text/css" />
```

But the CSS file is not loaded, I don't know why. Can you help me!

Comment: did you run the `assetic:dump` command? Is the `.css` file in the `/web/` folder ?

Comment: Yes I ran it and gave me : Dumping all dev assets. Debug mode is on. The .css file is also in the /web/ floder

Comment: Why are you not using `filter='cssrewrite'` and did you clear cache?

Comment: Because i have a simple .css file that does not contain any relative paths. Yes I cleared the cache.